# Google Analytics - need to let users know they're being anonymously tracked?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using google analytics in an android application via their sdk. Do I need to show end users any terms of service since analytics are being used, ie. notify them that their usage is being anonymously collected? Or, since it's all anonymous, I don't really have to show them anything? I'm just collected stuff like what screens are being viewed, nothing personal,

Thanks

Comment: It definitely wouldn't be impolite, but as far as required?  We'd need to know more information as this may vary by jurisdiction and/or primary function of the application.

Comment: Oh it's a board game type of app. I just wanted to know what parts of the app people are spending their time in, that kind of stuff. Downloads won't be restricted geographically.

Comment: Ok if I want to provide a privacy policy, is there a standard template available I can use? I searched around a few weeks ago but didn't see one specific to mobile apps + google analytics. I'm not collecting any other information on the users besides what google analytics provides.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need one specific to mobile apps or google analytics. You just need one that tells them you use tracking cookies for analytic purposes. I think the BBB has a good template to use IIRC. If you google sample privacy policy you'll find good templates for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not already have a terms of services screen, I would not add one just for that,the data collected is anonymous and is used purely to better develop the application in the future. Tracking system like that is almost a "standard" in the development of a website/apps to better understand our users.

It is also far from "privacy invasion" to know that 72% of users (let's say 100 000 users) check Highscore after their game or that 18% of users play more than 10 games...

Answer (score 1):

Let them know. It's a good practice and easy to do. A basic privacy policy, which can easily obtained online and edited to suit your needs, is all it takes. Plus it covers your butt in the unlikely case that someone gets bent out of shape about it. I'd say it's worth the five or ten minutes you spend on it.

Answer (score 1):

It's bit longer, but still can be important.

If you are using Google Analytics, you've already agreed to [their policies](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/policy).

> You will give your end users proper notice about the implementations and features of Google Analytics you use (e.g. notice about what data you will collect via Google Analytics, and whether this data can be connected to other data you have about the end user). You will either get consent from your end users, or provide them with the opportunity to opt-out from the implementations and features you use.